# SQL update a table

Tags: sql, postgresql, where-clause

**TABLE 1**

```
 id   name        uf        ibge
 1   GOIANIA     'GO'       null 
 2   BRASILIA    'DF'       null
 3   TOCANTINS   'TO'       null
```

**TABLE 2**

```
 id      name            uf       ibge
 1    GOI**Â**NIA       'GO'     5208707
 2    BRAS**Í**LIA      'DF'     5300108
 3    TOCANTINOPOLIS    'TO'     1721208
```

I need to update in table 1, the field `ibge` using some kind of `like` in the `where` clause to relate the `description` of the `city` with `ibge` code.

Could anyone help? Very grateful!

Comment: Sorry, could you be please give more details. And as far as I see you would be able to match records by the `uf` column.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you can join both tables on the `uf` field, like so:

```
UPDATE Table1
  SET ibge = Table2.ibge
  FROM 
    Table2
  WHERE 
    Table1.uf = Table2.uf;
```

[Fiddle here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!10/7f920/1)

Answer (score 1):

Try this...

```
UPDATE T1
SET T1.ibge = T2.ibge
FROM Table1 T1
INNER JOIN Table2 T2 
ON T1.id = T2.id
```

Comment: Who downvoted this answer? I really don't get it. I tried this on my SQL Server. It works. Whoever downvoted this probably doesn't know SQL. Whoever you are, please do leave a comment. I'm okay if I made a mistake. I stand corrected. But please provide a better answer.

Comment: Same here. Presumably the downvoter is fixating on the OP's requirement is to do some kind of proximity or Regex match to the proprietary encoding on the Table2 `name`s.

Comment: Yes Sir StuartLC and Anri. We try to provide a valid answer and people just hate on it. The OP just needed to update ibge in Table1 and he suggested some kind of solution. And since only fields id and uf are possible to use as reference, I just used the id field as connection to the second table. If the OP asked this kind of question, he probably doesn't realize the field 'name' cannot be used because values are different. That's why we guide and provide answers. Like I said, downvoting is alright, but whoever you are, provide a better answer :)

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE table1 tab1 SET ibge = (SELECT ibge FROM table2 tab2 WHERE tab1.name like (substring(tab2.name, 1, 3) || '%') LIMIT 1);
```

Assuming that the first 3 characters are the same in field name for table 1 and table 2